# having issue with cin.getline() when working with char data type

Tags: c++, c++17, getline

If I enter `12345` to `arr2`, why will the program skip the `cin.getline(arr3,6,'#')` and just finish?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text;
    char arr2[10];
    char arr3[6];
    cout << "enter value" <<endl;
    getline(cin,text);
    cin.getline(arr2,5,'#');
    cin.getline(arr3,6,'#');
    cout << "results : " << endl;
    cout << " arr1 is : " << text << endl;
    cout <<" arr2 is : " << arr2 << endl;
    cout <<" arr3 is : " << arr3 ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

example of execution :

```
enter value
mo
12345
results :
 arr1 is : mo
 arr2 is : 1234
 arr3 is :
Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Comment: And what result are you expecting?

Comment: And where is there arr1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I enter `12345` to `arr2`, why will the program skip the
> `cin.getline(arr3,6,'#')` and just finish?

The line `cin.getline(arr2,5,'#');` says that `arr2` is a pointer to an array of 5 chars. That size includes the `'\0'` terminator a proper C-style string needs.

So it can only read 4 chars from the input, and then add the terminator. When it finds more than 4 chars before the end of line, that it an input error.

So the stream sets its `fail()`-state and will not read anything more until the error condition is cleared.

Input to `arr3` is skipped, because the stream is already in an error state.

Answer (score 0):

the last parameter in cin.getline() is what indicates that the input is ended i.e. the delimiter. Replace the lines with your code to fix.

```
cin.getline(arr1,10,'\n');
cin.getline(arr2,10,'\n');
cin.getline(arr3,6,'\n');
```

The syntax is `cin.getline(your_array, max_characters, delimiter);`

`\n` means line break (In case of this code, it represents ENTER press)

---

**Don't forget to Declare arr1 as it's declaration is missing in your code...**

---